# Javascript sorting array quiz

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting

```
const questions = [
  {
    questionText: "What is the capital of France?",
    answerOptions: [
      { answerText: "New York", isCorrect: false },
      { answerText: "London", isCorrect: false },
      { answerText: "Paris", isCorrect: true },
      { answerText: "Dublin", isCorrect: false }
    ].sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5), //it sorts but when clicked it generate new random values(position change which is not good) in answerOptions1
    answerOptions1: [
      { answerText: "New York1", isCorrect: false },
      { answerText: "London1", isCorrect: false },
      { answerText: "Paris1", isCorrect: true },
      { answerText: "Dublin1", isCorrect: false }
    ].sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5) //it sorts but when clicked it generate new random values in answerOptions
  },
{},
{}
]
.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5) // this sorting is not working
;
```

codesanbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-zeh-5ulr5z?file=/src/App.js

I need to sort questions, answerOptions and answerOptions1 array in random order. The .sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5) is not working for this logic. When answerOptions is clicked, it also generate new random position in answeOptions1. answerOptions and answerOptions1 should not change their position and data/value(when fetch from large list).

Comment: `sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)` doesn't make sense. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#description

Comment: @evolutionxbox is right. The callback function in the sort method is supposed to return a value of 0, greater than 0 or less than 0

Comment: If you want to sort randomly check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

Answer (score 1):

Your randomly generated array will change in each render. use `React` [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) hook to generate random array once.

```
const questions = useMemo(()=>[
  {
    questionText: "What is the capital of France?",
    answerOptions: useMemo(()=>[
      { answerText: "New York", isCorrect: false },
      { answerText: "London", isCorrect: false },
      { answerText: "Paris", isCorrect: true },
      { answerText: "Dublin", isCorrect: false }
    ].sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5), []), //it sorts but when clicked it generate new random values(position change which is not good) in answerOptions1
    answerOptions1: useMemo(()=>[
      { answerText: "New York1", isCorrect: false },
      { answerText: "London1", isCorrect: false },
      { answerText: "Paris1", isCorrect: true },
      { answerText: "Dublin1", isCorrect: false }
    ].sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5), []) //it sorts but when clicked it generate new random values in answerOptions
  },
{},
{}
].sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5), [])
```

Comment: Thanks, useMemo works for answerOptions and answerOptions1 array but not working with questions array.

Comment: See my edited answer

Comment: I got error. please look at https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-zeh-5ulr5z?file=/src/App.js